# JavaScript calling function from external file gives .is not a fuction error, how can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

So, while I was using this require('fileName.js') to add an external JavaScript file to my main index.js file.

In the index.js

```
const caltor = require('./calculate.js');

console.log(caltor.adding(5,7));
```

In my calculate.js

```
function adding (i,y){
        return i+y;
}
```

BTW I am using nodejs to execute.

The error says:

```
console.log(caltor.adding(5,7));
                   ^
TypeError: caltor.adding is not a function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to export the function 'adding' in your 'calculate.js' file.

```
module.exports = adding;
```

in your index.js file, no need to call caltor.adding() (Assuming that you only export one function from 'calculate.js').

```
console.log(caltor(5,7));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help,  I would like more than one function to be called from that file is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: If you want more than one function to be called from that file, you can simply use:
exports.adding = adding;
exports.subtracting = subtracting;
exports.multiplying = multiplying;
but you need to call these function names in the file where you need them

Comment: I see that you got your answer. Sorry for the missing answer I gave, I just assumed you're importing a single function from your file.

Answer (score 2):

Node.js modules don't automatically export their top-level scope variables/functions.

To export a value, you have two ways:

- Add it to the `exports` object

  Node modules have a predefined variable `exports`, whose value is exported. Add your function to it:

  ```
  function adding (i,y){
    return i+y;
  }

  exports.adding = adding
  ```

  ```
  const caltor = require('./calculate.js');

  console.log(caltor.adding(5,7));
  ```

  You can also export multiple values this way, just be sure to giv them a different name:

  ```
  function adding (i,y){
    return i+y;
  }

  exports.adding = adding

  function subtracting (i,y){
    return i-y;
  }

  exports.subtracting = subtracting
  ```

  ```
  const caltor = require('./calculate.js');

  console.log(caltor.adding(5,7));
    console.log(caltor.subtracting(5,7));
  ```
- Providing a "default" export by assigning to `module.exports`

  If you want to export a single value, you can assign it to `module.exports`. In this case, it becomes the value returned by `require`.

  Note that after assigning `module.exports`, defining a property on the `exports` variable will no longer work. Neither will assigning to `exports` varible export anything.

  ```
  function adding (i,y){
    return i+y;
  }

  module.exports = adding
  ```

  ```
  const adding = require('./calculate.js');

  console.log(adding(5,7));
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help,  and is there any way to use that external file like a class in JavaScript I'll need more than one function from a calculator.

Comment: You can export multiple things using the first method (just give them a different name) or, if you want to create an instantiatable something (i.e. class), then create a class and export / use it in either way.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't get reply in time actually I was going to say that the exports object solution worked just as I wanted. I cant thank you enough. This was first ever stack overflow question to be answed in one day blew my mind. Thank you verry verry much FZs.